# setPixel() missing 1 required positional argument: 'color'

Tags: python, posterization

I'm using this program in college called Cengage Mindtap, which is very stringent on syntax and required outcomes. And I have been getting a type error. This is all running on a python Mindtap terminal thing, so I am not sure if the python idle or whatever would result in something else. Could anybody explain what the error would be caused by? Also the images file that is being imported is given code made by Mindtap.

'''

```
from images import Image

def posterize(image,rgb):
    whitePixel = (255,255,255)
    for y in range(image.getHeight()):
        for x in range(image.getWidth()):
            (nr, ng, nb) = image.getPixel(x,y)
            average = (nr + ng + nb)/3
            if average < 128:
                image.setPixel((x,y),rgb)
            else:
                image.setPixel((x,y),whitePixel)

def main():
    filename = input("Enter the image file name: ")
    red = int(input("Enter an integer [0..255] for red: "))
    green = int(input("Enter an integer [0..255] for green: "))
    blue = int(input("Enter an integer [0..255] for blue: "))                    
    image = Image(filename)
    posterize(image, (red, green, blue))
    image.draw()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

Well, your issue will be in this line:

```
image.setPixel((x,y),rgb)
```

And what Python is telling you is that you have not passed enough information to `setPixel`, it needs more.  I am guessing that `setPixel` wants your `x` and `y` coordinates separate instead of the tuple you provided.  Perhaps this will help:

```
image.setPixel(x,y,rgb)
```

This way `setpixel` gets 3 arguments instead of 2, which might be what it wants (I am unfamiliar with this module)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this library, so here's my shot in the dark:

I'm guessing the `Image.setPixel` method wants three arguments, `x, y, color`, not two arguments, `(x, y), color`.

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
image.setPixel(x,y,whitePixel)
```

Also needs coordinates separately. Here is the final version:

```
from images import Image

def posterize(image,rgb):
    whitePixel = (255,255,255)
    for y in range(image.getHeight()):
        for x in range(image.getWidth()):
            (nr, ng, nb) = image.getPixel(x,y)
            average = (nr + ng + nb)/3
            if average < 128:
                image.setPixel(x,y,rgb)
            else:
                image.setPixel(x,y,whitePixel)

def main():
    filename = input("Enter the image file name: ")
    red = int(input("Enter an integer [0..255] for red: "))
    green = int(input("Enter an integer [0..255] for green: "))
    blue = int(input("Enter an integer [0..255] for blue: "))                    
    image = Image(filename)
    posterize(image, (red, green, blue))
    image.draw()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```